# worldwind java documentation and set up instructions

Tags: java, worldwind

I am trying to understand NASA world wind java application. The developer guide in the [website](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/index.html?root=java) is not loading saying server down. Anywhere I can get the developer's guide for the java application. If possible, the setup instructions would be helpful as well.

Comment: Here: https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/index.html?root=web. This was literally the second entry when googling "nasa world wind developers guide"

Comment: @QBrute you are speaking about Web (HTML5 and Javascript documentation) but I am asking for Java documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer guide for WorldWindJava is hosted on https://goworldwind.org (which seems it was unavailable temporarily). Link mentioned by you actually gets its content for developer guide tab from https://goworldwind.org. It is now available: https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/index.html?root=java&javatopic=guide